# Verifying Logic On Insecure Password Changes

Tags: php, passwords, md5

I am a one man band, and have to fix a problem that someone created a log time ago. I have a client site that has passwords stored insecurely (plain text). I want to remedy this, but I just wanted to post up the process to make sure I am on the right track with converting to a hashed password (md5 most likely).

Here is my steps that I can believe I can tackle this problem.

1. Alter table to allow for larger encrypted password.
2. Add salt, previous password, and date last changed password to table.
3. Reset all passwords, storing all old passwords. Not sure whether to use plain text or md5 when storing old passwords.
4. Force users to change password. This process I am still out to jury on.

   - I would think I allow them to log in, verifying user, checking to see if the password is 32 characters or less.
   - If less, check past password for match.
   - If past password is a match, send out email with temporary token to a page to change password.

Does this sound reasonable processes? The part I am worried about is when they are forced to change their password. The other option is to just send them the token to change their password when they try to log in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you have the plaintext passwords of the user, why not just MD5 them ? in this case you do not need to check for a specific length and you have some instant security increase. check the salt if its defined or not, if not, its a converted md5. when the user transmits his new password bundle it with some random salt, store the new md5 and store the random salt so you know this is a converted hash.

Comment: I did forget to mention that I have reason to believe some passwords may have been compromised.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should separate between two issues:
1. encrypting the passwords using one-way encryption
2. making the clients change their password every 180 days or so

About #2: it's totally acceptable to ask users to change their passwords every period of time, but you shouldn't make it shorter than 180 days as it becomes very annoying...